# Conditionally Validation in Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

How to implement the condition like value of 1 field should always be greater than the value of another field.

here's my schema

```
   value: Yup.number().required(''),
   value2: Yup.number().when('value',{
     is: (val) => something here
    then: Yup.number().required('Required').positive('value should be positive'),
    otherwise: Yup.number()
  })
```

I want to check for value2 to always be > value. 
How to access value2's value in the when condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the right way to do it, but I'm using [test](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema).

Like this:

```
yourField: Yup.string().test('should-be-greather-than-yourField2', 'Should be greather than yourfield 2', function(value) {
  const otherFieldValue = this.parent.yourField2

  if (!otherFieldValue) {
    return true;
  }
  return value > otherFieldValue;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to compare **more than** condition between two fields

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

```
value: Yup.number().required(''),
value2: Yup.number().required()
   .moreThan(
    Yup.ref('value'),
    'Should be more than value2'
    )
```

Comment: this will fail if first value isint a required field

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try `is: (val) => Yup.number().moreThan(val)`

Answer (score -1):

I am validating same fields for email and mobile no  so user can validate both is same field.

```
  username: yup
      .string().when({
        is : value =>isNaN(value),
        then: yup.string().required('email/mobileno is required') .matches( Regex.EMAIL_REGX,
          'Invalid email',
        ),
        otherwise: yup.string()
        .matches(Regex.PHONENO_REGX, StringUtils.phoneNo)
      }),
```